# Bcrypt password hashing in Golang (compatible with Node.js)?

Tags: node.js, go, bcrypt

I set up a site with Node.js+passport for user authentication.

Now I need to migrate to Golang, and need to do authentication with the user passwords saved in db.

The Node.js encryption code is:

```
    var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        if(err) return next(err);

        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            if(err) return next(err);
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
```

How to make the same hashed string as Node.js bcrypt with Golang?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Using the [golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt](http://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt) package, I believe the equivalent would be:

```
hashedPassword, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword(password, bcrypt.DefaultCost)
```

**Working example:**

```
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    password := []byte("MyDarkSecret")

    // Hashing the password with the default cost of 10
    hashedPassword, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword(password, bcrypt.DefaultCost)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(hashedPassword))

    // Comparing the password with the hash
    err = bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword(hashedPassword, password)
    fmt.Println(err) // nil means it is a match
}
```

Comment: Thank you.

I use bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword to compare the password and the string written by node.js in db, and return nil.

Originally I thought the generated strings are always the same. Now I understand.

Really appreciate.

Comment: @user2036213: I have never used bcrypt before either and was a bit surprised that each run resulted in a new hash for the same password. But it still works fine. We learn new things every day :). Happy Go coding!

Comment: Erm, that's what the random salt is good for - to make sure that two users with the same password will not have the same (salted) hash. [Here](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)'s a lengthy but good background article.

Comment: @rob74: I see. I missed the fact that the hash produced by bcrypt includes the bcrypt version, cost, salt and cipher, not only the cipher (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6833165/694331). Thanks for the article!

Comment: This package seems to be slow and very cpu costly. Any alternative?

Comment: @majidarif The bcrypt algorithm is meant to be cpu costly to make it harder to brute force. You can even choose cost (iterations). I have not benchmarked Go's bcrypt package against other bcrypt implementations though, but I doubt there is any good Go alternative.

Comment: @ANisus, yeah, I guess that should be it. But I am not hashing, I am just comparing, and 1 "compare" is a sudden spike of `24%` cpu usage. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: @majidarif When comparing, the string is hashed as well; it is by design. To create a hash and to compare a hash has the same cost. I'd say it is working as intended :)

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the [bcrypt package](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse?repo=crypto#hg/bcrypt) from [go.crypto](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.crypto) (docs are [here](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.crypto/bcrypt)).

To install it, use

```
go get golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt
```

A blog entry describing the usage of the bcrypt package can be found [here](http://www.somethingsimilar.com/2012/05/24/finding-go.crypto-and-go.net/). It's from the guy who wrote the package, so it should work ;)

One difference to the node.js library you are using is that the go package doesn't have an (exported) `genSalt` function, but it will generate the salt automatically when you call `bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword`.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you need import the bcrypt package

```
go get golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt
```

Then use GenerateFromPassword

```
bs, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(p), bcrypt.MinCost)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Internal server error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
dataEncrypt, _ := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(yourData), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
```

the second parameter 'bcrypt' can take multiple values
and for compare you can use

```
error := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(yourDataEncript), []byte(dataText))
```

very useful for password use

Comment: Does it automatically create the salt?